# Put Text at bottom of Flutter page

Tags: flutter

In the application I developed with Flutter, I want to put a `Text` widget at the bottom of the page.

My codes:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:teen_software_stock_tracking_app/Controller/PaginationController.dart';

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore _store = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
PaginationController paginationController = PaginationController();

TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();

bool SeePassword = true;

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _passwordFocus = FocusNode();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passwordFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 108, 184),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 60),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column (
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Text("Giriş yap", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40, fontFamily: "Roboto Bold")),
                    SizedBox(height: 12),
                    Text("Hoş geldiniz.", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22, fontFamily: "Roboto Regular")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                  ),
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        Center(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 70,
                            height: 5,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 185, 185, 185),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.080),
                        const Text("E-posta:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 34, 34), fontFamily: "Roboto Medium")),
                        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.010),
                        Theme(
                          data:Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                            colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
                              primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 117, 203),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _emailController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 232, 232, 232),
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                            ),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Roboto Regular"),
                            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                              _passwordFocus.requestFocus();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.027),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const Text("Parola:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 34, 34), fontFamily: "Roboto Medium")),
                            const Spacer(),
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: const Text("Şifremi unuttum", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 108, 184), fontFamily: "Roboto Bold")),
                              onTap: () {
                                // send email of reset.
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.010),
                        Theme(
                          data:Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                            colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
                              primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 117, 203),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                            obscureText: SeePassword,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 232, 232, 232),
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock, size: 20),
                              suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                child: SeePassword ? const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye) : const Icon(Icons.highlight_off_sharp),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    SeePassword = !SeePassword;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Roboto Regular"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.030),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 50,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 117, 203),
                              ),
                              child: const Text("Giriş yap", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Roboto Bold")),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And app:

[image]

I want to put a `Text` at the bottom of the page. I tried with Align but got many errors. That's why I'm opening this thread. Additionally, I tried doing it with `Spacer()` and it still didn't work.

How can I do what I want? Could you help? I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You are using a column inside a SingleChildScrollView which causes the issue while using the Spacer().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your body in a Stack and add the code:

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Text('yourText'),
),
```

Do not forget to adapt your body with the Stack widget.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. `Text` moved to the bottom of the page. But this time, when the keyboard is opened, `Text` stays on the keyboard. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can try use `SingleChildScrollView` or adapt a boolean to hide the text when use keyboard, and show when dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your Text around Expanded widget and the adjust it

```
Expanded(
    child: .../ your Text widget
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I'm using [`bottomNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Your Button Text'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            fixedSize: const Size(double.maxFinite, 45),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Text(
      'Your Bottom Screen Widget',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    elevation: 0,
  ),
);
```

Result-> [image]